# Fancybox Open on Page Load

Tags: javascript, fancybox, fancybox-2

I open fancy box on page load. The fancybox loading fine but the external link doesn't open when I click on fancybox.

This is the div I use for fancybox

```
<div id="inline2" style="display:none;">
<a href="download.php" target="_blank"><img src="images/upgrade.png" border="0" /></a>
</div> <!-- end of inline2 -->
```

I use this code I use in the page head section

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#inline2").fancybox({ 
'padding':          0,
'cyclic':       true,
'width':        625,
'height':       350,
'padding':      0, 
'margin':      0, 
'speedIn':      300,
'speedOut':     300,
'transitionIn': 'elastic',
'transitionOut': 'elastic',
'easingIn':     'swing',
'easingOut':    'swing',
'titleShow' : false
}); 
$("#inline2").trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Could somebody please help me how to open the donwnload.php page when I click on fancybox?

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean with `the external link doesn't open when I click on fancybox`? does the link open in a new tab? what does fancybox do : does it close? what version of fancybox?

Comment: I use fancybox (fancyBox v2.0.6) to show a div when the page is loaded. div is an image. that image has instructions pls download. That image has a download button too. When the visitor click on that button (infact anywhere on that div image) he should go to the download.php.

Comment: It works when I show fancybox div on the site button click <a href="#inline2" class="fancybox"><img src="images/directions.png" border="0" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:35px;" /></a>. but when I load the fancybox in pageload it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Try this script...

```
$("#inline2").fancybox({ 
'padding':          0,
'cyclic':       true,
'width':        625,
'height':       350,
'padding':      0, 
'margin':      0, 
'speedIn':      300,
'speedOut':     300,
'transitionIn': 'elastic',
'transitionOut': 'elastic',
'easingIn':     'swing',
'easingOut':    'swing',
'titleShow' : false
}).trigger('click');
```

Comment: I've just tried your advice but now I cannot see the fancybox when the page is loaded.

Comment: ok I could solve it I used this with head section. <script type="text/javascript">
window.jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox.open('#inline2');
});
</script>

Comment: Thank you yeyene and all helped me